# SwiftUI: I want to show one random element everyday , even after relaunching the app

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui, set

I tried it before with random element it worked but when i shut the app and reopen it new element appears , what i want is to show one random element everyday.

Comment: Can you provide sample code which you tried?

Comment: can you post a sample or explain more what do you need and i'll post for you an answer

Comment: You need to persist the app state, UserDefaults is one option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a random element and then store it as a user preference using UserDefaults with the date. Store it as a dictionary with type [Date: String] (replace String with the type of the random element).

When generating which element to show, check if there is any entry for that date in the dictionary after reading it from UserDefaults. If there is, then read that random element, else generate a new random element and store it in the dictionary.

```
// Since you did not mention the element type, I am assuming it is of type Int. Change it to whatever suits your needs.
// Keep in mind: The types of the keys and values of the dictionary need to be supported by the defaults system, that is, strings, numbers, Date objects, and Data objects.

func randomElementIndex() -> Int {
    
    // fetch the dictionary stored in user defaults
    let key = "randomElementIndices"
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var dictionary = defaults.object(forKey: key) as? [Date: Int]
        ?? [Date: Int]()
    
    // fetch today's calendar components for later use
    let calendar = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent
    let now = Date()
    let components = calendar.dateComponents([.calendar, .year, .month, .day], from: now)
    let today = calendar.date(from: components)!
    
    if dictionary.keys.contains(today) {
        // app opened at least once today, so return that index instead of a new random index
        return dictionary[today]!
    } else {
        // replace this with your own custom random number generating algorithm
        let randomValue = Int.random(in: 1...100)
        
        // remove all previous entries in the dictionary, and just store this new one
        dictionary = [today: randomValue]
        
        return randomValue
    }
}
```

Comment: You don’t need to call synchronise on UserDefaults  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize Apple states **this method is unnecessary and shouldn't be used**

Comment: @Andrew Updated the answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing it out.